# Servidor remoto con tunel inverso, el puerto ocupado a veces se encuentra cerrado

Tags: linux, servidor, ssh

lo que pasa es que poseo dos servidores remotos (serv1 y serv2) lo que sucede es que cuando ingreso al serv1 para luego realizar el ingreso a traves del tunel inverso al serv2 hay veces que el puerto por el que ingreso se encuentra cerrado o no responde y en el terminal me devuelve "ssh: connect to host localhost port 2022: Connection refused"
Pero hay momentos en el que si logro acceder. Queria saber como puedo lograr mantener el puerto 2022 en este caso siempre abierto.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que haya un proceso que esté ocupando ese puerto. Simplemente puedes matar el proceso que esté en corriendo en ese puerto y luego conectarte pero primero revisa el proceso ocupa ese puerto. Entra con ssh y monitorea ese puerto con algún script, cronjob o con `watch` y con `sudo netstat -tlpn | grep 2022` o  con `sudo lsof -i tcp:2022`.

Eso es pensando que puede haber otro proceso utilizando ese puerto, tal vez si no se puede conectar, lo cierra y luego lo abre para conectarse.

Si yo estuviera en tu caso, eso sería lo primero que haría puesto que podría ser (en uno de los peores escenarios) una intrusión a través de ese puerto.

La otra es que intentes conectarte por otro puerto al servidor1 y por otro al servidor2, es decir.

#### Servidor1

Va a permitir conexiones a través del puerto, es un ejemplo de puerto, 2001 del servidor2 (remoto) al puerto 22 local. Es decir, el servidor2 se va a conectar a su localhost por el puerto 2001 (el uno se me ocurrió para indicar que es el servidor1).

```
ssh -N -f -R 2001:127.0.0.1:22 usuario@ip_servidor2
```

#### Servidor2

Va a permitir conexiones a través del puerto, es un ejemplo de puerto, 2002 del servidor1 (ahora es el remoto) al puerto 22 local. De forma análoga a la anterior.

```
ssh -N -f -R 2002:127.0.0.1:22 usuario@ip_servidor1
```

Y te puedes conectar al servidor2 desde el servidor1 con:

```
$ ssh usuario_de_servidor2@127.0.0.1 -p 2002
```

Y viceversa, del servidor2 al servidor1 con:

```
$ ssh usuario_de_servidor1@127.0.0.1 -p 2001
```

La explicación de lo que hacen los parámetros `-N`, `-f` y `-R` la puedes encontrar en `man ssh`. Pero en resumen `-f` envia todas las peticiones a background, `-N` no ejecuta ningún comando de forma remota y `-R` hace un port forwarding de la siguiente manera `-R <puerto del servidor remoto>:<host>:<puerto_local_de_conexión>` es decir, con ssh -R hacía un ip remota, le permite a ese servidor remoto conectarse a su propio host y su puerto local acordado y entrar por ahí al servidor que permitió esa conexión, le permite ver el tráfico. Y, en el caso del ejemplo anterior, como es al puerto de ssh (puerto 22), permite obtener una shell.

Recuerda que todo esto puede funcionar con tu par de llaves, o da igual, si sabes el password de ambos usuarios de ambos servidores también funciona.